# Integrating a multiple degree of freedom equation of motion

Tags: python, scipy, ode, numerical-integration

I would like to find the response of a simple dynamical system with 2 degrees of freedom, defined by ODE: `m ddx(t) + k ddx(t) = f(t)`. The system is excited with force `f1 = f01 * sin(omega*t)` at point 1:

[image: 2 degree of freedom dynamic system]

The mass and stiffness matrices are defined as follows:

```
import numpy as np

m1 = 10
m2 = 8

k1 = 1e6
k2 = 3e6
k3 = 7e6

m = np.diag([m1,m2])
k = np.array([[k1 + k2, -k2],
              [-k2, k2 + k3]])

omega = 500  # excitation angular frequency
```

The mass matrix inverse:

```
minv = np.linalg.inv(m)
```

The integration functions:

```
def cantilever_beam_ode_with_external_excitation(t, initial_state):
    """
    ODE for a cantilever beam with external excitation (force())
    EoM: m ddx + k x = f
    """
    # unpack the state vector
    x = initial_state[0]  # vector
    xd = initial_state[1]  # vector, unimportant, since no damping

    f = force(t)

    xdd = minv.dot(-k.dot(x) + f)

    # return the two state derivatives
    return [xd, xdd]

def force(t):
    force = np.zeros(m.shape[0])
    f0 = 100
    force[0] = f0 * np.sin(omega*t)
    return force
```

The integration parameters and integration:

```
# initial conditions
x0 = np.zeros(m.shape[0])
dx0 = np.zeros(m.shape[0])
initial_state = (x0, dx0)

integrator = 'vode'
state_ode_f = integrate.ode(cantilever_beam_ode_with_external_excitation)
state_ode_f.set_integrator(integrator, nsteps=500, rtol=1e-3, atol=1e-5, first_step=1e-2)

t_start = 0
t_final = 1

state_ode_f.set_initial_value(initial_state, t_start)

time = np.array([t_start])
velocity = np.expand_dims(initial_state[0], axis=0)
acceleration = np.expand_dims(initial_state[1], axis=0)

print("#\t Time\t\t Timestep \t state_ode_f.successful()")
i = 1

while state_ode_f.t < (t_final):
    state_ode_f.integrate(t_final, step=True)
    time = np.append(time, state_ode_f.t)
    velocity = np.append(velocity, np.expand_dims(state_ode_f.y[0], axis=0), axis=0)
    acceleration = np.append(acceleration, np.expand_dims(state_ode_f.y[1], axis = 0), axis=0)
    print("{0} \t {1:0.5f}\t {2:0.4e} \t {3}".format(i, state_ode_f.t, time[-1] - time[-2], state_ode_f.successful()))
    i += 1
```

I get the following message as a result:

```
C:\Anaconda3\python.exe D:/faks/LADISK/python/CMS_sparse/integrators/FEM_simple.py
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_ode.py:853: UserWarning: vode: Illegal input detected. (See printed message.)
#    Time        Timestep    state_ode_f.successful()
  'Unexpected istate=%s' % istate))
4500     0.00000     0.0000e+00      False
 DVODE--  RWORK length needed, LENRW (=I1), exceeds LRW (=I2)
      In above message,  I1 =       116   I2 =        52
4501     0.00000     0.0000e+00      False
 DVODE--  RWORK length needed, LENRW (=I1), exceeds LRW (=I2)
      In above message,  I1 =       116   I2 =        52
4502     0.00000     0.0000e+00      False
 DVODE--  RWORK length needed, LENRW (=I1), exceeds LRW (=I2)
      In above message,  I1 =       116   I2 =        52
4503     0.00000     0.0000e+00      False
 DVODE--  RWORK length needed, LENRW (=I1), exceeds LRW (=I2)
      In above message,  I1 =       116   I2 =        52
...
```

Any ideas on how to solve the problem are welcome.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure that your packing and unpacking of the state vector/matrix always gives the expected results?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you are defining the state as a list (or tuple) of arrays (each 3 elements).  The `ode` on the other hand expects a scalar, array, or list (of scalars).

I can get it to run (but can't guarantee the values are correct) by turning the state in to 1 longer array:

```
state_array = np.hstack(initial_state)
```

And wrap your function with one that reshapes and hstacks the results

```
def fn(t, state):
    # try raveled state
    state = state.reshape((2,-1))
    dd = cantilever_beam_ode_with_external_excitation(t, state)
    return np.hstack(dd)

state_ode_f = integrate.ode(fn)
state_ode_f.set_integrator(integrator, nsteps=500, rtol=1e-3, atol=1e-5, first_step=1e-2)

t_start = 0
t_final = 1
delta_t = 0.1

state_ode_f.set_initial_value(state_array, t_start)

for i  in range(20):
    state_ode_f.integrate(t_final, step=True)
    print(i,state_ode_f.t)
    print(state_ode_f.y.reshape((2,-1)))
```

produces values like:

```
(0, 0.001)
[[  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00  -1.42857119e-08]
 [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00  -1.42857119e-05]]
(1, 0.00125)
[[  0.00000000e+00   9.76562337e-10  -2.00892823e-08]
 [  0.00000000e+00   4.10156182e-06  -2.34374957e-05]]
(2, 0.0015)
[[  0.00000000e+00   3.02734325e-09  -2.82366021e-08]
 [ -1.46484351e-07   1.03759748e-05  -3.57561308e-05]]
(3, 0.00175)
[[ -1.31835916e-10   8.00781113e-09  -4.13295119e-08]
 [ -6.93054082e-07   2.14355430e-05  -5.38674361e-05]]
...
(19, 0.006110558142273646)
[[ -2.41150395e-06   1.60094544e-05  -1.55746906e-05]
 [ -3.78656683e-03   2.36296597e-02  -2.20818279e-02]]
```

Comment: Thank you, this works for me. I am a little confused, beacuse I need to wrap my function, in order that the integration runs successfully. Why is that? To be more precise, why does the `state` variable need to be in it?

Comment: I updated my question with an analytical solution. I also changed the example (from 3DOF to 2DOF system).